# How to group by new expression with multiple select statement

Tags: sql

```
SELECT date_uploaded,
       (SELECT CAST(tablename.date_uploaded AS date) AS Expr1) AS newdate
  FROM tablename
```

My question is, how to `GROUP BY` the new dummy column given (`Expr1`)?

Answer (score 1):

In most databases, you need to repeat the condition in the `group by`:

```
SELECT date_uploaded, CAST(tablename.date_uploaded AS date) AS newdate
FROM tablename
GROUP BY CAST(tablename.date_uploaded AS date);
```

The nested `SELECT` is utterly unnecessary for a simple expression.  I have no idea where people learn to do such things, but I have seen similar examples in the past.

Comment: Thanks ya i will revert back to you asap

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way:

```
SELECT * FROM
(

        SELECT date_uploaded,
        (SELECT CAST(tablename.date_uploaded AS date) AS Expr1) AS newdate
        FROM tablename

 )AS TB  

GROUP BY TB.newdate
```